# mySQL - Select records based on value in order, then random records in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

I'm looking to have one mySQL query where I can select all records set to a particular value, then selecting a number of other records from the records left, in a random order.

To explain, here's an example: (`MyTable` database table)

```
ID        Name        SomeValue
1         Fred        0
2         Jake        0
3         Jone        1
4         Bill        0
5         Greg        0
6         Thom        2
7         Jane        3
8         Erin        0
```

So first, I'd want to select all records where `SomeValue` is more than 0. The appropriate mySQL query for this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeValue > 0 ORDER BY SomeValue DESC
```

This would return:

```
7         Jane        3
6         Thom        2
3         Jone        1
```

Next (in the same query), how would it be possible to select 3 other records at random (limit 6), from the ones remaining?

So that the end result of records returned looks something like this:

```
7         Jane        3
6         Thom        2
3         Jone        1
5         Greg        0    // Randomly picked
1         Fred        0    // Randomly picked
8         Erin        0    // Randomly picked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where somevalue > 0
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where somevalue = 0
 order by rand()
 limit 3
);
```

If you want the values ordered by `somevalue` add `order by` somevalue as the last line of the query.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Out of curiosity, is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @VolcovMeter . . . This is very reasonable.  If you have a large table and many values are `0`, then you might be concerned about performance.